# ggplot: how to get same bar widths across different facets

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I regularly have to create plots similar to the one below. What somewhat annoys me with the result is the location and the size/(bin)width of the bar in the facet B.

Ideally, I would like to have the bar positioned on the same level/height as the bar of c in facet A and the two remaining 'spaces' (where a and b are located in facet A) remain empty in facet B.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~group, ~unit, ~value,
     "A",   "a",    10L,
     "A",   "b",    15L,
     "A",   "c",    20L,
     "A",   "c",    25L,
     "B",   "d",    10L
  )

df %>% 
  ggplot()+
  geom_bar(aes(x=unit,
               y=value),
           stat="identity")+
  facet_wrap(vars(group),
             scales = "free_y")+
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

I am aware that I can use `scales="free"` or use `patchwork`, `cowplot` package etc. But as far as I can tell, none of these approaches would yield the desired result.

Any idea? Many thanks!

Comment: See: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2774; if you do `scales = "free_x"`, the bars will have the same widths, but the result is probably not what you are after.

Answer (score 2):

Only way I can think of is to hard-code the widths of the bars:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = unit, y = value))+
  geom_col(width = c(0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.35)) +
  facet_wrap(vars(group), scales = 'free_y')+
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: many thanks! This already solves one issue, irrespective of the drawback of hardcoding. Any idea on how to modify the location of the bar (to align it with the 'c' bar in facet A')? Maybe something like creating some dummy categories (e, f) with value NA and omit their axis labels in facet B?

Comment: Yes you could try that strategy, I don't have any better ideas. If that works, you probably don't need to adjust the widths anymore either.